# Exception while uploading file to S3 .Net SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have written a small uploader to upload files using AWS S3 .NET SDK. It works fine on my computer. When I tried it on the two of the client computers, it throws exceptions.My dev machine and the client machine are running Windows 7. I tried couple of other computers, the program works fine. It is a very simple program, reads a file and calls the SDK API to upload it. The exception I am getting are:

```
Faulting application name: AWSUploader.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp:        0x56df54b2
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23313, time stamp: 0x56842940
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c44d
Faulting process id: 0x1594
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1798c224555b4
Faulting application path:   C:\Users\ama06v\Desktop\Debug\Debug\AWSUploader.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 602f959e-e57f-11e5-a925-70f39532fcec


Application: AWSUploader.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException
Stack:
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon, Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.IMarshaller`2<Amazon.Runtime.Internal.IRequest,Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceRequest>, Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.ResponseUnmarshaller)
at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.InitiateMultipartUpload(Amazon.S3.Model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest)
at s3.amazon.com.docsamples.UploadFileMPULowLevelAPI.Main(System.String[])
```

I have opened a ticket with AWS, they are looking into it, so far no answer form them.
I am using the latest AWS SDK from NuGet 3.2.2

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a lot, found out that the exception I was getting is an uncaught exception. This exception has nothing to do with the KERNELBASE.dll, this is not the culprit, although it looks like. So I added a handler for unhandled exception not knowing where the exception was happening like this:

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
```

Handler

```
static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

That handler produced the following exception (truncated):

```
MyHandler caught : A WebException with status ProtocolError was thrown.
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: A WebException with status Protocol Error was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.GetRequestContent()
......
......
```

Basically the hospital system had a proxy server that was blocking our request to AWS!! Needed to login to the Proxy server as the defualt logged in user. For that you add the following line to the app.config.

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials=”true”> </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

I hope this helps somebody.